# Maximum amount of colorbox on a site?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Is there a maximal count of colorboxes (http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)  on a site?

I use colorbox for showing more details on click on a table row by making an ajax request on click. The colorbox reacts fine and as expected but only up to the 20th row of my table.
But starting from the 21th table-row no JS-event is fired, no error in the js-console is shown. Just nothing happens.
Any suggestions?

Comment: We don't have a massive crystal ball on our desk! Supply us with code to recreate the problem so we can help you further!

Comment: Adding some code of how you use `colorbox` might help you get answers.

Comment: Ok, I've tried some things. If I have a static table, there a no limitations. But if I build my table by `tabulator` (http://tabulator.info/),  then the issue occurs. I will post example code, if I'm figured out it more precise. Thank for your willingness!

Comment: So ... update.
I integrate know `colorbox` in my with `tabulator` generated tables by tabulator - callbacks and this works fine.